# Perl: Meaning of double squared brackets after a string?

Tags: perl, square-bracket

I don't understand a seemingly basic piece of code in Perl, which looks like this:

```
$line[$k][1]
```

What is the meaning of the double squared brackets?

I'm sorry if this was already asked or is so basic it can be found in every beginners book for Perl. I couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: It's an element of a 2D array. That is an array which for elements has array references (like `my @ary = ([1, 2], [4, 5]);`). Then what you ask is the `1`-indexed element of the arrayref which is the `@line` array's `$k`-indexed element. The full syntax is `$line[$k]->[1]` but (here) the arrow may be dropped.  In my `@ary` example `$ary[1][1]` is `5`.

Answer (score 1):

It means you're working with a two dimensional array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @stuff = ( 
   [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
   [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
 );

 print $stuff[1][2]; 
 #prints '7'
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that what you have there is not "a string". It's an array called `@line` and that every element in `@line` is a reference to another array.

When you access a single element in a Perl array, the sigil changes from `@` (which implies multiple values) to `$` (which implies a single value). So to look up the element with index `$k` in an array called `@line`, you use:

```
$line[$k]
```

But in your example, `$line[$k]` contains a reference to another array. To get from an array reference to one of the elements of the referenced array, we use the `->[...]` syntax. So the second element of the array referenced by the `$k`th element of `@line` is given by:

```
$line[$k]->[1];
```

And in Perl, we have a rule that when two sets of array (or hash) look-up brackets are separated by just a dereferencing array, we can omit that arrow. So my previous example can be simplified to:

```
$line[$k][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

A `[..]` is an array index. If you've got 2 of them, that means it's an array of arrays. In your example you're getting the 2nd element (indexes start at 0) of the `$k`th element of `@line`.

That you think it's a string is possibly a sign the code isn't very well written as there should be a line saying something along the lines of `my @line;`

Make sure the code has `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top and that should throw up any problems with the code.